# How to get a field with the type of timestamp in mysql through odbc using cpp in windows

Tags: c++, mysql, timestamp, odbc

I create a table `a_tb` using the following sql in mysql command line:

```
create table a_tb( id int not null auto_increment, w_time timestamp default current_timestamp,a int default -1, PRIMARY KEY ( id ));
+--------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field  | Type      | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+--------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id     | int(11)   | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| w_time | timestamp | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| a      | int(11)   | YES  |     | -1                |                |
+--------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

And I use `insert into a_tb (a) values (2);` Then I get:

```
+----+---------------------+------+
| id | w_time              | a    |
+----+---------------------+------+
|  1 | 2016-11-22 17:09:34 |    2 |
+----+---------------------+------+
```

What I want to do is to read data from `a_tb` by using C++ through ODBC.
I have read msdn and successfully have the access to get the data from the table by using the code like [Connecting to a MySQL server using C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860480/connecting-to-a-mysql-server-using-c).
Each field is ok except timestamp, which I always get some bizarre numbers. And what I have tried is as follows:

```
SQLTIMESTAMP tt[14];
SQLGetData(hstmt, 2, SQL_C_TIMESTAMP, tt, 0, &cbTestInt);
```

and I get [image]

in the console
and

```
time_t tt;
SQLGetData(hstmt, 2, SQL_C_TIMESTAMP, &tt, 0, &cbTestInt);
```

I get `4222219140663264`.
and

```
SQLINTEGER sTestInt, cbTestStr;
SQLGetData(hstmt, 2, SQL_C_ULONG, &sTestInt, 0, &cbTestInt);
```

I get `2016`.

But what I want to get is `2016-11-22 17:09:34`. I am puzzled through trying many method...

Answer (score 0):

That number is the numerical representation of the `timestamp`. It is the number of seconds past since (I believe) 1970-01-01. If it is not an integer, but a real number, the value after the . is the number of microseconds.

Now that we understand the beast, let's see how to fight it. You could implement a function which gathers the year, month, day, hour, minute and second from that number, but that would be an unintuitive solution. Instead, you could use [strftime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/) to convert that number into date.

Comment: but I think `4222219140663264` cannot be convert to a reasonable time by `strftime`